# python pulp, if statement using pulp.variables

Tags: linear-programming, pulp

Recently, I come across some problem when using Pulp.

I define my problem like this.

```
point = lp.LpProblem("Maximize the Points", lp.LpMaximize)
#the dict can only be string, so we use a list containing string
students = [str(i) for i in list(range(96))]
groups = [str(i) for i in list(range(24))]

choices = lp.LpVariable.dicts("Choice",(groups,students),0,1, cat = "Integer")
```

In order to solve my linear programming problem, my objective is so complicated that I need to employ some self-written functions to solve it. It is like this,

```
point +=  1 * cal_lang() \
        + 1 * cal_leader() \
        + 1 * cal_learn() \
        + 1 * cal_like() \
        - 10 * cal_dislike() , "Maximize the evaluation points"
```

Meanwhile, in the cal_lang, I need to calculate the number of how many variables equals 1 so I use

```
if lp.value(choices[group][student]) == 1 :
```

However, this does not works even though pulp.value defined like.

> pulp.value(x)
>              Returns the value of the variable/expression x, or x if it is a number.

```
print('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%')
print(choices["5"]["5"])
print(type(choices["5"]["5"]))
print(lp.value(choices["5"]["5"]))
print('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%')
```

This is so confused. Then I try to extract the type and value of my variables. The code and output is like this.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Choice_5_5
<class 'pulp.pulp.LpVariable'>
None
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

It seems that I can out extract the value of my variable chioces["5"]["5"] which is defined integer 0 or 1 and my "if" does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's hard to follow your code or what you are doing after all. You can't use just any external operator, if-else's or external functions acting on variables (other than affine forms) inside the model. If you use ```varaible.value``` or something similar before doing something to the final solution, you are probably doing something wrong. So try to be more precise about what you are doing and try to minimize/extract the core of your problem

Comment: The value of a variable is not defined before the solution is found. I suggest you look at the examples

Answer (score 0):

*I need to calculate the number of how many variables equals 1*

As `choices` is a binary variable. this is super easy:

```
 count = sum((i,j), choices(i,j))
```

(in math-like notation). This can be transcribed directly in Pulp using `lpSum`.